# Using injectGlobal styled-components API with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to use simple injectGlobal API but can't make it work with typescript. I have the following setup in theme.tsx

```
import * as styledComponents from "styled-components";
import { ThemedStyledComponentsModule } from "styled-components";
import IThemeInterface from "./theme";
const {
  default: styled,
  css,
  injectGlobal,
  keyframes,
  ThemeProvider
} = styledComponents as ThemedStyledComponentsModule<IThemeInterface>;
export default styled;
export { css, injectGlobal, keyframes, ThemeProvider };
```

And in my App.tsx I simply do

`import { injectGlobal} from '../theme.tsx'`

and try to use it normally but there is always the following erro

`unused expression, expected an assignment or function call`

Looking for any advice!

Comment: What line of code is the error reported on?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Error is on the line where I call ```injectGlobal`
    * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
`;```

Comment: Side note for any other readers from the future: `injectGlobal` was [deprecated](https://medium.com/styled-components/styled-components-v4-new-final-finalest-for-real-final-final-psd-fa4d83398a77) three weeks after this post in V4, and replaced by [`createGlobalStyle`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this error is from the [tslint no-unused-expression rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-unused-expression/).  You can exempt calls to template tags like `injectGlobal` from the rule by adding the `allow-tagged-template` option in your `tslint.conf` like this:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unused-expression": [true, "allow-tagged-template"]
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that!